# RBS Migrate() Did Not Complete?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, rbs, remote-blob-storage

My SharePoint file size is 47GB. I use sp migrate to move files out of database onto files system for RBS migration. SP Migrate() only Migrated 9gb.

Where are the rest of my files?

Did Migrate() Fail?

Or did I not estimate the total file size correctly?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Microsoft's RBS? It shouldn't be used outside of SQL Express scenarios. RBS also does not migrate file sizes under the specified size.

Comment: I followed the below link                                 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631.aspx

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631.aspx

Comment: Content database is about 57GB and the file size in AllDocs 47gb . If I understand correctly 47GB is the file size. I would like to migrate this file onto file system.

Comment: What benefit do you hope to gain? Microsoft's RBS is for those leveraging SQL Express due to the 4/10GB MDF limit (depending on version). It is a detriment to those using SQL Standard/Enterprise requiring more overhead and additional maintenance. RBS performs *worse* for blobs under 256KiB, which will be *most* standard Office documents in SharePoint. I also believe the default value is to only migrate blobs out of the database which are >= 100KiB.

Comment: Please see the links below those links could answer your questions. https://www.sharepointeurope.com/media/104852/avepoint_optimize_sharepoint_storage_with_blob_externalization.pdf https://www.sharepointeurope.com/media/104852/avepoint_optimize_sharepoint_storage_with_blob_externalization.pdf

Comment: Yes, but you're not using a 3rd party RBS provider which that article is pushing. Microsoft's RBS was strictly created for the SQL Express users, which isn't what you're using in your environment. I think you're misunderstanding the intent of Microsoft RBS.

Comment: Trevor, yes I agree with you. I might miss understand . what you recommend me for my environment?

Comment: If you want to use RBS, go with a 3rd party. In a vast majority of farms, RBS (3rd party, not Microsoft's) offer little actual benefit. Microsoft's RBS has a singular purpose which is to allow those using SQL Express to maintain a larger dataset as SQL Express is limited to 4 or 10GB MDFs, depending on version.